# error ! Package xkeyval Error: `A4' undefined in families `Gm'. while trying to compile a template of the JIS journal in latex

Tags: errors, packages, xkeyval

(UPDATE)
I am trying to compile the template of a journal. I'm new to Latex, this is my first project, I'm using TexMaker to compile and run my LaTex files, already downloaded MikTex to install packages whenever I need, and the compiler gives me this error log: [error log](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6l6l80tb5tgkyam/log.txt?dl=0)

I'm trying to compile a template of this link (and I didn't change a single line of this JIS journal template): https://sol.sbc.org.br/public/downloads/Template_JIS_1.0.zip

the sample tex I'm trying to ompile is in this link: [JIS template](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hzhk7gijy1j7yk3/sbc-sample.tex?dl=0)

What am I doing wrong? I'm completely new to latex, and any help would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance for your attention.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please never post screenshots of code or error messages (your screenshot is even unreadable, because of the low resolution). Instead, help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The error message of the screenshot is not readable. Zooming into the original image also does not help, because of the low resolution. So please do not only show a minimal working example (as explained) but also copy the original error message from the `log` file into the question.

Comment: The class file passes the option 'A4' to the geometry package. This is wrong (maybe the author meant 'a4paper'). However, after I fix that I get another error. Something is seriously wrong with these files!